# How to send verbatim requests over a socket with Perl?

Tags: perl, http, httprequest

I need to send requests that are formatted exactly as I specify, including whitespace. What's the best way to achieve this?

Example of the kind of request I want to send:

```
GET
/
key=val
Host:example.com
```

The protocol is a simple request-response protocol like HTTP. I'd prefer to take advantage of LWP's existing code where possible.

Comment: @raina77ow Is there any way to do this using LWP without subclassing HTTP::Request?

Comment: What did you try? And what about responses? Do you want to handle them yourself or do you want a module which will do it for you?

Comment: @MichałGórny: I've searched the CPAN. I suppose I could open my own sockets, or edit the LWP source, but I feel like there is a simpler way that I'm missing.

Comment: @MichałGórny: The only thing I need to do myself is the request format. I'm happy with LWP's timeout handling and all, for example. I need to send a specific request and read the response.

Comment: @Andreas So IO::Socket family is not relevant either?

Comment: @raina77ow: I suppose it is, if there's no better solution :) Just trying to minimise wheel re-invention.

Comment: That's not HTTP. Adjusted question. I made a few guesses based on your comments, so feel free to correct.

Comment: To use LWP, you need to write an `LWP::Protocol::something` object and request an `something://...` URL to use your object.

Comment: @ikegami: I just read the relevant RFCs and you seem to be right. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is be achievable with LWP. It's a bit of work, to be honest.

I've take a look at it, and you need to actually implement your own protocol (see `LWP::Protocol`) because that's where the actual request is created. Afterwards, you will need to enable that protocol as implementor of http (or https):

```
LWP::Protocol::implementor('http', 'MyFunkyProtocol');
```

For an example, take a look at `LWP::Protocol::GHTTP` code.

Simply saying, you need to create a package implementing a `request` method. In that method, you need to assemble the request, open the connection, send it and receive the response.

---

Here's a simple working example.

MyFunkyProto.pm:

```
package MyFunkyProto;

use LWP::Protocol;
@ISA = qw/LWP::Protocol/;

use HTTP::Response;
use IO::Socket;
use Carp qw/croak/;

sub request
{
    my ($self, $request, $proxy, $arg, $size, $timeout) = @_;

    my $remote = IO::Socket::INET->new(
        Proto     => "tcp",
        PeerAddr  => "example.com",
        PeerPort  => "http(80)"
    ) or croak('unable to connect');

    my $message = <<EOF;
GET
/
key=val
Host:example.com
EOF

    $remote->print($message);
    $remote->flush();

    local $/;
    my $resp = HTTP::Response->parse(<$remote>);

    $remote->close();

    return $resp;
};

1;
```

script.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use lib '.';

use MyFunkyProto;
use LWP::Protocol;
use LWP::UserAgent;

LWP::Protocol::implementor('http', 'MyFunkyProto');

my $fr = HTTP::Request->new('GET', 'http://www.example.com/');
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();

my $r = $ua->request($fr);
print $r->as_string();
```

Note that you will actually want to construct the request (and obtain the host and port) from the `$request` object. Or if you're lazy, just store it somewhere in that object.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you may use [IO::Socket::INET](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/IO-1.25/lib/IO/Socket/INET.pm) module. Here's a bit shortened [example](http://www.rocketaware.com/perl/perlipc/TCP_Clients_with_IO_Socket.htm) of using it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use IO::Socket;
my $host = '127.0.0.1'; # an example obviously
my $remote = IO::Socket::INET->new( 
   Proto     => "tcp",
   PeerAddr  => $host,
   PeerPort  => "http(80)",
);

my $message = <<MSG;
GET
/
key=val
Host:example.com
MSG
unless ($remote) { die "cannot connect to http daemon on $host" }
$remote->autoflush(1);
print $remote $message;
while ( <$remote> ) { print }
close $remote;
```

In other words, go a bit lower in a protocols hierarchy. )